# Python DateTime formatting issue

Tags: python

I have the below setup to convert the dateTime string from a JSON to a DateTime variable in Python.

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(item.published.strip(), '&a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

below is the error, where is my formatting going wrong?

ValueError: time data 'Wed, 21 Jul 2021 05:00:00 +0000' does not match format '&a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues. First, you need `%z` at the end. `%Z` is a time zone name (like UTC). Second, you have a typo at the start - you need `%a` instead of `&a`:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(item.published.strip(), '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes:

1. %a instead of &a.
2. %z instead of %Z

Code with correction:

```
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt.strip(), '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```